# Merge [windowmanager] and [window-managers]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

These tags mean the same thing: [windowmanager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windowmanager) and [window-managers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/window-managers). I'd prefer they be made synonyms for (the non-existent) [window-manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/window-manager) though.